# The instance of entity type 'TblCompany' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{paramID: 2}' is already being tracked

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am having a problem with updating a row in my database using ef.

Here are the error I am getting:
`System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'TblCompany' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{paramID: 2}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.'`

Below here is my original code:

```
public ServiceResponse<TblOverridee?> UpdateOverridee(TblOverridee overridee)
        {
            try
            {
                var tempOverridee = _db.TblOverridee.Find(overridee.paramID);

                if (tempOverridee == null)
                {
                    return new ServiceResponse<TblOverridee?>
                    {
                        Data = null,
                        Time = DateTime.Now,
                        IsSuccess = false,
                        Message = "No Product Found"
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    tempOverridee.paramPct = overridee.paramPct;
                    tempOverridee.Product = overridee.Product;
                    tempOverridee.ProductId = overridee.ProductId;
                    tempOverridee.Company = overridee.Company;
                    tempOverridee.CompanyId = overridee.CompanyId;
                    tempOverridee.paramOverrider = overridee.paramOverrider;
                    tempOverridee.paramOverriderId = overridee.paramOverriderId;
                    tempOverridee.paramDesc = overridee.paramDesc;
                    tempOverridee.paramSalesPersonID = overridee.paramSalesPersonID;
                    tempOverridee.paramUpdatedOn = DateTime.Now;

                    _db.SaveChanges();

                    return new ServiceResponse<TblOverridee?>
                    {
                        Data = tempOverridee,
                        Time = DateTime.Now,
                        IsSuccess = true,
                        Message = "TblOverridee Updated"
                    };
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new ServiceResponse<TblOverridee?>
                {
                    Data = null,
                    Time = DateTime.Now,
                    IsSuccess = false,
                    Message = "TblOverridee error updating: " + ex.Message
                };
            }
        }
```

On my startup I'm using `service.AddTransient<..>` instead of `services.AddSingleton<..>` or `services.AddScoped<..>` ,I've tried changing into the other and it still doesnt work.
Currently I am still using this:
`services.AddTransient<IOverrideeService, OverrideeService>();`

I have another code same as the one above and it is working perfectly fine.

I've tried to detach the existing entity before attaching the new entity using the code below but unfortunately it still is not working:

```
var existingCompany = _db.TblCompany.Find(overridee.Company.paramID);
if (existingCompany != null)
{
    _db.Entry(existingCompany).State = EntityState.Detached;
}
_db.Entry(overridee.Company).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

I've tried this just incase it was a problem:

```
if(overridee.Company!= null)
{
     var cmpny = _db.TblCompanies.Find(overridee.Company.paramID);
     overridee.Company = cmpny;
     overridee.CompanyId = cmpny.paramID;
}
```